# What is dereferencing possible null pointer?

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception, dereference

I am making a program for `SFTP` in `NetBeans`.

Some part of My code:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.Session sessionTarget = null;
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp channelTarget = null;
try {
       sessionTarget = jsch.getSession(backupUser, backupHost, backupPort);
       sessionTarget.setPassword(backupPassword);
       sessionTarget.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
       sessionTarget.connect();
       channelTarget = (ChannelSftp) sessionTarget.openChannel("sftp");
       channelTarget.connect();

       System.out.println("Target Channel Connected");
       } catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured ======== Connection not estabilished");
            log.error("Error Occured ======== Connection not estabilished", e);
       } finally {
            channelTarget.exit();     // Warning : dereferencing possible null pointer
            channelTarget.disconnect();  // Warning : dereferencing possible null pointer
            sessionTarget.disconnect();  // Warning : dereferencing possible null pointer
        }
```

I'm getting warning `dereferencing possible null pointer`, how can I resolve these warnings???
Where I can disconnect my `Session` and `Channel`???

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sessionTarget = jsch.getSession(backupUser, backupHost, backupPort);` Here in this line, `getSession()` method can throw an Exception, and hence the variables `sessionTarget` and `channelTarget` will be null, and in the finally block, you are accessing those variables, which may cause null pointer exception.

To avoid this, in the `finally` block check for null before accessing the variable.

```
finally {
  if (channelTarget != null) {
       channelTarget.exit();     
       channelTarget.disconnect();  
  }
  if (sessionTarget != null ) {
       sessionTarget.disconnect();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That means: what if your `channelTarget` and `sessionTarget` are null in your finally block? Check them for null to avoid the warning.

Answer (score -2):

I think netbeans is just trying to warn you that these may be null which may not be necasarilly true. You can choose to disable the warnings though. Just place your cursor on the warning press `ALT+ENTER` and choose from the choices even to disable the warnings.

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to ignore/disable a warning unless you know for a fact that everything will be okay. Disabling this kind of warning does *not* fall under that category; if you might be dereferencing null, figuring out at compile time is *much* better than having to debug a NullPointerException.